# Rails: Favoriting System - models associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following model associations setup were a consumer can favorite a product or a variant. I just wanted to ask if my approach is correct?

```
class Favorite < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :consumer
  belongs_to :favorited, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :product, optional: true
  belongs_to :variant, optional: true
end

class Consumer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :favorites
  has_many :favorite_products, through: :favorites, source: :favorited, source_type: 'Product'
  has_many :favorite_variants, through: :favorites, source: :favorited, source_type: 'Variant'
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :favorites, dependent: :destroy
end

class Variant < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :favorites, dependent: :destroy
end

class CreateFavorites < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :favorites do |t|
      t.references :consumer, index: true
      t.references :favorited, polymorphic: true, index: true
      t.integer :product_id
      t.integer :variant_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Take a look at this http://schmidt-happens.com/articles/2014/06/04/favoriting-system-in-rails.html. It might help you!

Comment: Thanks for the help @Theopap. I have already read this one. Based on this setup I created my model associations. But in my case instead of a project, I have products and variants. Still not sure if what I came up though is the correct approach. Any ideas if the model associations I have are correct?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear why you have both polymorphic `favorited` and separate relation on `product_id/variant_id`. Usually one would go with one of these approaches.
Polymorphic associations can be unidirectional too - `has_many :favorites, as: :favorited, dependent: :destroy`

If you go with separate columns for each relation - indexes on `product_id` and `variant_id` may also be useful to prevent full table scan on product/variant deletion (on `dependent: :destroy`, also if you do not expect callbacks/nested relations there - `delete_all` is faster).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Vasfed. So you're basically suggesting to delete the `product_id & variant_id` from the migration and replace this `has_many :favorites, dependent: :destroy` with this `has_many :favorites, as: :favorited, dependent: :destroy` on both the product & variant models? Also everything else stays the same?